# How to deploy wcf service on amazon elasticbeanstalk,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS Toolkit to deploy the wcf service on amazon elastic beanstalk, after deployment it shows environment is healthy but when i browse the URL then it redirected to the IIS Server Page, i am unable to access the service url , please let me know how to access the hosted service

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow the standard  procedure to deploy a ASP.net project. Here is the link for that : [Link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/index.html?tkv-deploy-cloudform.html)

But for you WCF service you need a  simple html page at project root. E.g. index.html or default.html.  Load balancer need this page to check if the instance is available or not.  Without this html page load balancer will consider the instance dead and remove it.